# Expressing non-Hermitian Dynamics in general and in the Heisenberg picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution, dissipation, open-quantum-systems

Suppose I have an open system governed by a master equation

$$\frac{d}{dt}\hat{\rho} =-i\left[\hat{H},\hat{\rho}\right]+\gamma\left(2\hat{J} \hat{\rho}\hat{J}^{\dagger}-\hat{J}^{\dagger}\hat{J}\hat{\rho}-\hat{\rho}\hat{J}^{\dagger}\hat{J}\right),$$

valid for any jump operator $\hat{J}$. It is well known that when we can neglect irreversible processes, that is we can neglect the jump term $\hat{J} \hat{\rho}\hat{J}^{\dagger}$, the dynamics can be rewritten as $$ \frac{d}{dt}\hat{\rho} =-i\left(\hat{H}_c \hat{\rho}-\hat{\rho}\hat{H}_c ^{\dagger}\right), $$ where now the dynamics are governed by the non Hermitian Hamiltonian $$ \hat{H}_c=\hat{H}-i\gamma\hat{J}^{\dagger}\hat{J}.$$ This is obviously not equivalent to $$\frac{d}{dt}\hat{\rho} =-i\left[\hat{H}_c,\hat{\rho}\right].$$

I was wondering how other forms of the Schrodinger equation look like for non Hermitian dynamics. For example in the Heisenberg picture I would think that now an operator $\hat{O}$ evolves according to $$\frac{d}{dt}\hat{O}=-i\left(\hat{O}\hat{H}_c-\hat{H}_c^{\dagger}\hat{O}\right)$$ (assuming no explicit time dependence in the operator itself).

Can we still say that the time evolution operator is contained within now a non-unitary of the form $$ \hat{U}=e^{-i\hat{H}_c t}?$$ What happens to the corresponding Schrodinger equation $$i \frac{d}{dt}\hat{U}=\hat{H}\hat{U}?$$

And are there any techniques to simulate those dynamics?

Comment: Well, a solution to $\frac{d}{dt}\hat{\rho} =-i\left(\hat{H}_c \hat{\rho}-\hat{\rho}\hat{H}_c ^{\dagger}\right),$ certainly is of the form $\rho(t)= U\rho U^\dagger$ with the $U$ you quoted. Then from this you get $i \frac{d}{dt}\hat{U}=\hat{H}\hat{U}$ and its complex conjugate. As a side note on non-hermitian hamiltonians (that satisfy the SE), it is of special importance if $H$ is PT symmetric, as has been extensively studied, cause then its spectra is real and positive. But I'm not too sure if that answers your question haha

Comment: I guess that if $J \rho J^\dagger$ terms are zero, you can use the "Monte Carlo" wave-function method where you evolve with $U$ and normalise at each step (as norm is no longer conserved). See for instance the original paper http://www.phys.ens.fr/~dalibard/publi3/osa_93.pdf . You would just ignore the jump term I suppose.